# Unable to get response when I hit a URL from JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, json, url

I have a strange question. There is a URL which gives response when I try to hit from POSTMAN Rest Client with "Interceptor" set. But when I try to hit the same URL from the JavaScript code it gives the following error with a response code of 403:

Body:

```
{
  errorCode ":102,"
  errorMessage ":" (102) Invalid session.You must be in a session to access this page.If you were logged in , your session may have timed out.Please log in again.
}
```

Headers:

```
{
  set - cookie: ["JSESSIONID=2D1EA3DA7EA57D558AA0569091BA06C3; Path=/companyName/; HttpOnly;Secure"]
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are not authenticated, and the page you are trying to access requires you to be authenticated to see the contents. You'll need to set your code up to authenticate, and **then** attempt to view that page.

Comment: I have already logged in to the page and hitting the URL

Comment: You say that, the server clearly has another opinion. :-)

Comment: Its possible that the javascript is triggering some kind of MOD SECURITY rule on the server. If it works fine from POSTMAN then you need to look at the Headers that postman is sending and set the Javascript Headers to the same thing.